# overdrawn balance error on cleos system newaccount

Tags: nodeos, cleos

I create 3 different account already, but i try to create new account with this:

```
cleos system newaccount eosio --transfer kyc1 <PUBLIC_KEY> 
    --stake-net "100000000.0000 SYS" --stake-cpu "100000000.0000 SYS" --buy-ram-kbytes 1024000

Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: overdrawn balance
pending console output:
```

I am getting `overdrawn balance` error, i try to find a solution on web then found this 
[Github issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/issues/137). And it says use this command:

```
cleos push action eosio init '[0, "4,EOS"]' -p eosio@active
```

When i use it, i get this console output:

```
Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: system contract has already been initialized
pending console output:
```

What can i do for create new account ?
nodeos --version v1.8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran this command then i can create new account.

`cleos push action eosio.token issue '["eosio", "400000000.0000 SYS", "memo"]' -p eosio`

Answer (score 0):

An overdrawn balance means exactly that. You don't have enough money to transfer the funds, buy the ram, and create the account.
In your case, you had a testnet where the base currency should have been SYS, but you hadn't issued any SYS tokens to the `eosio` system contract yet. Once you did that you could successfully transfer some of those SYS tokens to another account and buy RAM using those SYS tokens.